# Check Is Anagram Scala HashMap based implementation

Tags: algorithm, strings, functional-programming, scala

Here is the HashMap based implementation of the function checking whether two strings are anagrams:

Example:

```
isAnagram("SAVE", "VASE") // returns true
isAnagram("SAV",  "VASE") // returns false
isAnagram("SAVE", "VAS")  // returns false
isAnagram("SAVE", "VAEE") // returns false
```

My implementation:

```
def isAnagram(value1: String, value2: String): Boolean = {
  value1.length == value2.length && {
    val index = new mutable.HashMap[Char, Int]()

    def addToIndex(c: Char) = index(c) = index.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1

    value1.foreach(c => addToIndex(c))

    def decrementAndCheckInIndex(c: Char): Boolean = index.get(c) match {
      case None => false
      case Some(count) => index(c) = count - 1; true
    }

    value2.forall(decrementAndCheckInIndex) && index.forall { case (key, value) => value == 0 }
  }
}
```

Could you please provide feedback on this code. I am interested in the mutable data structure use here, is it ok? And in general, what can I make better?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `groupBy()` will do something very similar to your `addToIndex()`. The result is an `immutable.Map[Char,String]` instead of a `mutable.HashMap[Char, Int]`, so the question is: which is better/easier for comparison purposes.

It turns out that the simple `==` evaluation is sufficiently deep to handle this.

```
def isAnagram(value1: String, value2: String): Boolean =
  value1.groupBy(identity) == value2.groupBy(identity)
```

Another, rather obvious, anagram test is simply:

```
value1.sorted == value2.sorted
```

I think, for long strings, grouping/indexing might be more efficient than sorting since each string is traversed only once. On the other hand, comparison for equality might be more complex for `Map`s than it would be for `String`s.